# Replace string in first 3 lines of a file

Tags: python, replace

I have a file similar to this:

```
This is a letter B
This is a letter B
This is a letter B
This is a letter B
This is a letter B
This is a letter B
```

Using python, I'd like to replace the first 3 lines with an X.  For example:

```
This is a letter X
This is a letter X
This is a letter X
This is a letter B
This is a letter B
This is a letter B
```

The code I'm using changes every line:

```
for line in fileinput.FileInput(File,inplace=1):
        line = line.replace('B','x',3)
        print line
```

Any suggestions on replacing the first 3 only or as to why the line.replace is not honoring the 3?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just iterate over three times `range(3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program might do what you want:

```
import fileinput
File = 'bbb.txt'

for line in fileinput.input([File], inplace=1):
    if fileinput.filelineno() <= 3:
        line = line.replace('B', 'x')
    print line.rstrip('\n')
```

Note the use of `fileinput.input()` instead of `fileinput.FileInput()`. The `.input()` call establishes global state, including the ability to call `.filelineno()`.

Note the use of `fileinput.filelineno()` to determine the line number. The program performes the replacement on the first three lines.

Note the use of `.rstrip('\n')` to remove the original newline character. A newline will be implicitly added by the `print` operation.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling

```
line.replace('B','x',3)
```

inside the for-loop, which means you are replacing up to 3 B's in each line. (Not 3 B's in the whole file.)

To do what you like (in Python) you could increment a counter for each line read and only do the replacement if your counter is less than 3 (or 4, if you number lines starting at 1.)